# Repeat two words n number of times in a single formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I want to repeat two words n number of times specified from a reference using a single formula with the result being a dynamic array.

For example, if the two words are `Hello` and `Adam` and I need the two words to repeat 3 times, I would like the result to show in a row as shown in the table below:

| column A | column B | column C | column D | column E | column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | Adam | Hello | Adam | Hello | Adam | Adam |

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use CHOOSE and SEQUENCE

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(SEQUENCE(,A3*2,0),2)+1,"Hello","Adam")
```

Where A3 holds the number of repeats:

[image]